# How to integrate Zatca Fatoora Portal Phase 2 with Dynamics AX or D365?

Tags: sdk, integration, microsoft-dynamics, sandbox, dynamics-ax-2012

I have implemented Zatca's phase 1 Generation phase (KSA) and now I am working on implementing Phase 2 but I am confused about how to create Invoice XML file, get UUID, Hash Value, and what should be the complete pattern of the Invoice XML file.

Can anyone please tell me step by step how to implement Zatca Phase 2 with Dynamics AX 2012 or D365?

Comment: Seems phase 2 will not be supported until January 1st, 2023: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365-release-plan/2022wave1/finance-operations/dynamics365-finance/electronic-invoicing-service-saudi-arabia-e-invoice-integration-public-preview

Comment: Thank you @FH-Inway. Yes, I think I have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

First download these tools https://sandbox.zatca.gov.sa/downloadSDK
Then follow this brochure
https://sandbox.zatca.gov.sa/20220623_Developer%20Portal%20User%20Manual_vF.pdf

**Read on until another time they have technical linking problems I don't advise you to take the risk, their libraries are sterile and impractical (:**

The security processes on the invoice are incorrect and the certificate on his signature has expired since 2021

Comment: Thank you so much @clerk. I have already gone through that developer manual but couldn't find the integration part with third-party apps. I think there is time until January 1st 2023.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).